# What is the ppi of the MacBook Pro retina 13" when at a resolution of 1680x1050?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I know the resolution when it's at the retina resolution of 2560x1600, but what about when it's scaled to 1680x1050?

Answer (score 1):

Does 148.96 PPI seem correct?

[PPI Calculator](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html)

Comment: Does that correlate directly, though? With all the scaling?